# Trigger to stop a record from inserting more then 10time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on sql server 2008, i have situation in which i want to have a check on a column value that same value should not be inserted more than 10 times

my table is

```
uID       devs 
---------------
 1        SLS 
 2        SRS
 3        SLS
```

i want to have a check on devs, that same values should only be recorded 10times, not more than that. kindly guide me

Comment: What should happen if there are currently, say, 9 rows, and an insert attempts to add 2 rows? Also, what should the general behaviour be when the limit is exceeded? Silently discard old rows or new rows, or throw an error, or something else?

Comment: Create a trigger with post-insert action. Declare an integer variable value @ counter, then select:
SELECT @ counter = COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE devs = NEW.devs
If @ counter > 10 perform DELETE of dev with the biggest uID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (select count(*) from dev where devs='sls')<10
insert into dev values (0,'SLS')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add check constraint on your table

```
CREATE FUNCTION CountByDevs()
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Count INT

        SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM MyTable group by devs having COUNT(1)>10
        RETURN @Count
    END


    ALTER TABLE MyTable add CONSTRAINT Chk_MaxDevsAllowed
        CHECK (dbo.CountByDevs() <= 10)
```